# Facebook account got deleted for no reason, without warning or notification

Tags: facebook, account-management

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but my friends facebook account got deleted. Whats the best way of enquiring about this as they aren't replying to emails!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this Help Article](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=1048) on Facebook as to how your friend can contest this.  You won't be able to do anything, it has to be the account owner that contacts Facebook.

Specifically they should read this section:

> #### My Personal Facebook Account is
>   disabled
>
> There are different reasons why you
>   may not be able to access your account
>   and unique ways to contact Facebook
>   for each case. Therefore, it is
>   important to be sure that you are
>   using the correct channel when
>   submitting a request for help. First,
>   identify the correct reason why you
>   are unable to access your account from
>   the three reasons that are listed
>   below. Then, follow the instructions
>   listed by the reason that pertains to
>   you.
>
> 1. **Disabled for violating Facebook's Statement of Rights and
>      Responsibilities**
>       Facebook accounts that have been reported or detected for policy
>      violations may be disabled by
>      Facebook. Possible reasons include,
>      but are not restricted to:
>
>    - Continued prohibited behavior after receiving a warning or multiple
>        warnings from Facebook
>    - Unsolicited contact with others for the purpose of harassment,
>        advertising, promoting, dating, or
>        other inappropriate conduct
>    - Use of a fake name
>    - Impersonation of a person or entity, or other misrepresentation of
>        identity
>    - Posted content that violates Facebook’s Statement of Rights and
>        Responsibilities (this includes any
>        obscene, pornographic, or sexually
>        explicit photos, as well as any photos
>        that depict graphic violence. We also
>        remove content, photo or written, that
>        threatens, intimidates, harasses, or
>        brings unwanted attention or
>        embarrassment to an individual or
>        group of people)
>
>    Please review Facebook’s
>      [Statement of Rights and
>      Responsibilities](http://www.facebook.com/terms.php) to learn more
>      about specific types of conduct and
>      content that are not permitted on the
>      site.
>
>    If you have not posted violating
>      content or otherwise violated the
>      Statement of Rights and
>      Responsibilities, click [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=disabled).

Comment: Cheers Barry! I'll get them to send this form:
http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=disabled

Answer (score -1):

There are different reasons why you may not be able to access your account and unique ways to contact Facebook for each case. Therefore, it is important to be sure that you are using the correct channel when submitting a request for help. First, identify the correct reason why you are unable to access your account from the three reasons that are listed below. Then, follow the instructions listed by the reason that pertains to you